# How to include in django template a reverse url in translation

Tags: python, django

I have the following block of code, And I want to include a url to the login page, after the user logs out, in a translatable text.

Unfortunately, translation blocks cannot include tags, and I get the following error:

SyntaxError: Translation blocks must not include other block tags: url "account:login"

```html
{% blocktrans %}


You have been successfully logged out.


You can <a href="{% url "account:login" %}">log-in again</a>.


{% endblocktrans %}
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views



app_name = 'account'



urlpatterns = [

    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),

    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

What would be the right way to achieve something like this?

Edit: I figured there are workarounds, such as translating blocks of text separately, or using javascript to append the "href" element after the page loads. But I wonder if there is a more efficient, Django way.

Comment: can you show your urls.py

Comment: @iklinac Sure, edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag)

> Reverse URL lookups cannot be carried out within the blocktrans and
> should be retrieved (and stored) beforehand:
>
> ```
> {% url 'path.to.view' arg arg2 as the_url %}
> {% blocktrans %}
> This is a URL: {{ the_url }}
> {% endblocktrans %}
> ```

Comment: Doesn't quite answer how to include it in a template inside a block of text, and will not work with other tags, or custom ones